# Java FX change Label text in a previous stage scene

Tags: java, javafx, controller, label, fxml

I have a `Main` class starting my application which has its `MainController` class specified in fxml. When clicking on `Connect` button another windows with different scene and controller is opened. Based on action I would like to change `Label` text value through my `MainController`, but it does not work as expected. See details below.

Basically I would like to update text on `connectedLabel` in `MainController` class from `ConnectController` class and it does not work.

`Main.java`:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            logger.info("Application is starting");
            AnchorPane page = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));

            //BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            //Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Main.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            primaryStage.setResizable(false);

            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

`MainController.java`:

```
    public class MainController implements Initializable {

    private Context context = null;

    @FXML
    Label connectedLabel;
    @FXML
    Button connectButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        context = Context.getInstance();
    }

    public void setConnectedLabel(String name) {
        connectedLabel.setText(name);
        connectButton.setText("Disconnect");
    }

    @FXML
    public void connectTokenButton_onMouseClicked() {
        try {
            if (connectTokenButton.getText().equals("Disconnect")) {
                boolean disconnected = context.getToken().disconnectToken();
                if (disconnected) {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                    alert.setTitle("Disconnected");
                    alert.setHeaderText(null);
                    alert.setContentText("Succcessfully disconnected!");

                    alert.showAndWait();

                    connectedTokenLabel.setText("N/A");
                    connectTokenButton.setText("Connect");
                }
            } else {
                AnchorPane page = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ConnectView.fxml"));

                Stage stage = new Stage();

                Scene scene = new Scene(page);
                scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("ConnectView.css").toExternalForm());
                stage.setScene(scene);

                stage.setResizable(false);
                stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                stage.initOwner(connectedLabel.getScene().getWindow());
                stage.show();

                //Stage thisStage = (Stage) connectedTokenLabel.getScene().getWindow();
                //thisStage.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

`ConnectController.java`:

```
public class ConnectController implements Initializable {

    private Context context = null;

    @FXML
    ComboBox<String> selectComboBox;
    @FXML
    PasswordField userPinPasswordField;
    @FXML
    Button cancelButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        context = Context.getInstance();
    }

    public void setMainC(Stage stage) {
        mainStage = stage;
    }

    @FXML
    private void connectToken_onMouseClicked() {
        String pin = userPinPasswordField.getText();
        boolean connected = context.connect(selectComboBox.getValue(), pin);        
        if (connected) {

            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Connected");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Succcessfully connected!");

            alert.showAndWait();

            FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
            MainController mainController = myLoader.getController();
            mainController.setConnectedTokenLabel(context.getConnectedName());

            Stage thisStage = (Stage) selectComboBox.getScene().getWindow();
            thisStage.close();
        }
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong when calling `setConnectedLabel` method from different controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
MainController mainController = myLoader.getController();
mainController.setConnectedTokenLabel(context.getConnectedName());
```

Without calling the `load` method of the `FXMLLoader`, no controller instance is created, even if the `fx:controller` attribute is specified in the fxml file.

However calling `load` before `getController` will not help, since the fxml is just loaded again with a different controller instance.

You need to "tell" the `ConnectController` about the `MainController` it was created from. (see [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml))

One way would be to add this code to the `ConnectController` class

```
private MainController mainController;

public void setMainController(MainController mainController) {
    this.mainController = mainController;
}
```

and use this field instead of the local variable in the `connectToken_onMouseClicked()` method.

To call the setter, access the controller after loading the view in `connectTokenButton_onMouseClicked()`:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ConnectView.fxml"));
AnchorPane page = loader.load();
loader.<ConnectController>getController().setMainController(this);
```